# Algorithm to traverse a double dimension matrix

Tags: algorithm, multidimensional-array, matrix, double

Given a double dimension matrix with all positive numbers how do I traverse the matrix from one corner to the other such that the sum of values along the path is maximum?
You can move only left, right, up or down i.e cannot move diagonally.

You cannot move backwards i.e you always have to move towards the other corner

Comment: Sounds like Project Euler #83 (http://projecteuler.net/problem=83)

Comment: Are you allowed to visit all the numbers? If not, this is an assignment from NCPC or ICPC.

Comment: Maximum? For each value `k`, you can get a higher value by "looping" on some neighboring cells. Some more restrictions?

Comment: If you allow all of left-right-up-down movements then you can get an arbitrarily large value - is there any other restriction?

Comment: "You cannot move backwards" contradicts "move left, right, up and down". The two possibilites I can think of are "moving only right and down" and "you are not allowed to visit entries twice".

Comment: Yes that is correct, you can move only right and down

Comment: @user730304: If the answer you accepted does not fit you - you should unaccept it - to attract more viewers. Also - it is usually best to accept an answer only after at least a few hours - in order to get a variety of answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try a boustrophedonic traversal.  I repeat the advice to comply with SO's minimum posting length.  Try a boustrophedonic traversal.

Comment: You cannot move backwards i.e you always have to move towards the other corner

Comment: That's it, change your question after I've started answering it.  What you may find, if you refine your question enough, is that you answer it yourself.  Which will vindicate my unhelpful approach to helping you.